# wmic useraccount command returns failure

Tags: wmic

On my windows 2012 domain controller I have run the following command in cmd.exe

`wmic useraccount where "name='myusername'" set disabled=true`

Here are results:

```
Updating property(s) of '\\MYDCONTROLLER\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="
Mydomain",Name="myusername"'
ERROR:
Description = Generic failure
```

User is domain user. The same happens in powershell. I really have a reason to manage users via wmic.